# What is a Joule in Work

Tags: energy, work, si-units

I understand that in terms of work done, 1 Joule is 1 newton exerted through a distance of one meter, following that logic, 2 Joules would equal 2 newtons exerted over a distance of two meters, right (*this to me makes sense, but mathematically doesn't work out*)? Also, I know that there are multiple ways to get the same Joule, so wouldn't 2 Joules also equal a force of 2 Newton's applied over a distance of 1 meter? W=F*d

What I want to understand is Joules not actually describing the physical events that take place (*force and displacement are*), but how it compares that physical event in reference to something else that is equivalent like the example I gave above about 2 Joules?

Here is another example, with 490J which is 490N·m, it is also 490m·N and can it be described as 490 Newton's exerted over a distance of 490 meters? Would that still be equivalent?

I know I am probably confused about something simple here, but it isn't clicking, what I have read on joules don't explicitly answer my doubts.

Comment: If the math doesn't work out, then you need to recalibrate your own intuition. Two joules can be transferred through a 1 N force acting over 2 m or a 2 N force acting over 1 m, but definitely not a 2 N force acting over 2 m. That would correspond to 4 J.

Comment: *"following that logic, 2 Joules would equal 2 newtons exerted over a distance of two meters,"* You aren't following any logic. The original statement was just a definition. Why do you think you should increase every number in the definition by the same amount? That is the "logic" you are using, but you have made it up yourself; it isn't following from anything.

Comment: 490 n exerted over 490 m is 240,100 J. 490 N over 1 M is 490 J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No no, you are getting confused. As you already said One Joule is 1 Joule is 1 newton exerted through a distance of one meter.

Joules measure how much energy you need to give to the system to move it from point A to point B. And, as you rightly said it is measured by W=F*d. So $490 J$ is $490 N$ over 1 metre as $490*1=490$ also it is $1N$ over $490$ metres. It is also $70 N$ over $7$ metres as $70*7=490$ but it definetely isn't 490 N over 490 m as that would be 490 times 490J. Not equal to 490J. It is essentially a kind of tug of war between Force and displacement, for a given work done you can either apply a huge force over a small distance or a small force for a long distance, either way you provide the same energy to the system.

Comment: So, just energy stays consistent not both sides of the equations, thanks for clarifying, I need to rethink that, you can have that same energy (Joule) but it can mean different things based on how you get it. This seems hard to get an intuition of but looks like I just have to accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very good answer, short and to the point. I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused in what a **newton.metre** actually is.

See, 10 N.m does not mean 10 newtons of force over 10 meters, that would be equal to a 100 Nm or 100 joules. The dot thing you see in between is a symbol for multiplication, as I'm sure you know.

So, 10 Nm = (x N)*(y m), where x and y can be any numbers, as long as *xy=10*.

So, 490 Nm can mean 490 newtons force over 1 metre, or 1 newton force over 490 metres, or even 70 newtons force over 7 metres.

If you do any of these, you'll do 490 Joules of work.